# .NET async/await task runs without await

Tags: .net, asynchronous

Have one line of code:

```
var task = await TaskEx.Run(()=>{ Thread.Sleep(100000) });
```

That works as should be.

But if i write without await:

```
var task = TaskEx.Run(()=>{ 
    Thread.Sleep(100000);     //breakpoint
});
```

Why am i reaching breakpoint? Isnt that just a reference to task?
I am using .net 3.5 asyncbridge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing the misunderstanding that you might have: `TaskEx.Run` not only creates a task - it starts it as well. `await` does not start a task - it just pauses the method until the awaited task completes.

Comment: Can i create task without running? Tried TaskCompletionSource but that didnt help.

Comment: Task task = new Task(()=> Thread.Sleep(2000));// Task created. Task.Run will start it.

Comment: Yes you can but this is very unusual and almost never useful. It is also dangerous because most code assumes that tasks are started or will complete eventually.